# In Mozilla Browser, how to bring calender on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to display the paid bill details between the selected dates using HTML5 input type attribute 'date'. But it is not working in Mozilla Firefox.

```html
From:
<input type="Date"><br />
To:
<input type="Date">
```

Comment: You'll need to implement a date picker yourself, as Firefox doesn't support the HTML5 date type in the same way as other browsers.

Comment: you could do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/6e888hm0/

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported on IE and Firefox and Safari.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime